# How to convert rtf files in folder to PDF

Tags: sas, ms-office

Would anyone happen to know how to convert multiple .rtf (Rich Text File) placed in folder to PDF within `R` or `SAS`?

I cannoot install any application onto my pc so the solution should be only within the two programs I stated above.

Here is amended code generously provided by @Reeza:

```
bRecursive = False
sFolder = "C:\PATH"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
ConvertFolder(oFolder)
oWord.Quit

Sub ConvertFolder(oFldr)
  For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
    If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "rtf" Then
        Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.path)
        Str = left(oFile,instr(1,oFile,".")-1) 
        oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Str, 17
        oDoc.Close
    End If
Next

If bRecursive Then
    For Each oSubfolder In oFldr.Subfolders
        ConvertFolder oSubfolder
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

The above .vbs code works but I have 50 files in folder and after about 10 converted `rtf` do `pdf` docs it just keep opening and closing remaining files in circle (it seems). Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: rtf is not Microsoft Word file... its Rich Text File...

Comment: Did you already look at `pandoc` ? it could convert to and from various format (and PDF using Latex). `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert` can be used to call pandoc from R as the utility is included in `rmarkdown` package

Comment: you are right about pandoc .... but how to do it within `R`  ...

Comment: Can you use X commands? Honestly this is much easier in VBS which doesn't actually require any additional software.

Comment: @Reeza, yes X commands I'm allowed to use...

Comment: Here's a VBS script I used for DOC to DOCX conversion. If you change it to RTF and point to the folder I believe it will work. You can use the X command to call the VBS script.

Comment: @Reeza: I cannot see the VBS script, no link, thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/c7cab12c48133abefc2b4c84f264b290

Comment: @Reeza: I cannot figure out. In the code "x" string when changed it adds whatever is in string to the existing file extention *.rtfx for example (you just used doc to docx). But how to adapt this to save it as PDF file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the code, Change 12 to 17 and I'll leave it to you to figure out how to change the extension on your own.

Comment: ok it works, the solution is: Str = left(oFile,instr(1,oFile,".")-1) 
            oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Str, 17

Comment: @Reeza: The above solution is failing...I have about 50 files...first few are openned and saved as pdf but then the rtf files keep opening without saving them as pdf....anyclue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try adding the PDF extension? Post your code as an edit or new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this and it works fine on my system. Windows 7 Enterprise.
The VBS script is saved as a .vbs and then SAS can call it using an X command or %SYSEXEC.

The VBS script is:

```
bRecursive = False
sFolder = "C:\_LOCALDATA\temp\_rtf_test\"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
ConvertFolder(oFolder)
oWord.Quit

Sub ConvertFolder(oFldr)
  For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
    If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "rtf" Then
        Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.path)
        Str = left(oFile,instr(1,oFile,".")-1) 
        oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Str & ".pdf", 17
        oDoc.Close
    End If
Next

If bRecursive Then
    For Each oSubfolder In oFldr.Subfolders
        ConvertFolder oSubfolder
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Then in SAS:

```
%sysexec "C:\_LOCALdata\SAMPLE.VBS";
```